Getting issue dependency was found while adding dagger hilt
I am running a project with Jetpack Compose. And I'm using Kotlin DSL. And I added the dagger hilt to my project and I'm having an issue with the project.

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Hilt Android Gradle plugin is
applied but no com.google.dagger:hilt-android dependency was found.

dagger-hilt-android = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hilt" }
devtools-ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp" }

hilt version is 2.44 or 2.51.1 and 1.9.20-1.0.14 I tried with the difffent version of ksp also.
Add plugin on main build.gradle.kts
alias(libs.plugins.dagger.hilt.android) apply false
alias(libs.plugins.devtools.ksp) apply false

Add plugin on the app build.gradle.kts
alias(libs.plugins.devtools.ksp)
alias(libs.plugins.dagger.hilt.android) // If I add this in a plugin I'm getting the error.

When I'm building the project getting issues

A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
The Hilt Android Gradle plugin is applied but no com.google.dagger:hilt-android dependency was found.

And I follow those steps too - Dependency injection with Hilt

Did you used Kapt or Ksp ?

Ksp in the project and I already mention it above

Hilt supoorts ksp from V2.4.8

I already mentioned those above I was trying with hilt 2.51.1 too.

You might missing dependency in build.gradle(aap) and also share your both gradle file app-level as well as project-level

Add dependency is compulsory? I mean Just want to add plugin first then I will add the dependency. @ChiragThummar

Yes, You need plugin in dependency both at same time. can you share more code please?

I tried. And it works for me. I need to add the dependency at the same time while adding the plugins. @ChiragThummar Thank You

We need to add the dependency at the same time while adding plugins. It will not work with the adding plugins only. Thank you to 
Chirag Thummar
Add dependencies
hilt-android = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android", version.ref = "hilt" }
hilt-android-compiler = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hilt" }

Add bellow code on app level build.gradle.kts too.
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.hilt.android)
    ksp(libs.hilt.android.compiler)
}


Good to see it works

I ended up resolving this issue by adding this line to my top-level build.gradle.kts file:
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) apply false
    ...
}


Full dependencies:
libs.versions.toml:
[versions]
...
agp = "8.2.2"
hilt = "2.51.1"
hiltNavigationCompose = "1.2.0"
ksp = "2.0.0-1.0.21"
kotlin = "2.0.0"
...

[libraries]
hilt-android = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android", version.ref = "hilt" }
hilt-android-compiler = { group = "com.google.dagger", name = "hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hilt" }
hilt-navigation-compose = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose", version.ref = "hiltNavigationCompose" }
...

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
compose-compiler = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.compose", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
kotlin_serialization = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization", version.ref = "kotlin" }
hilt = { id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hilt" }
devtools-ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp" }

build.gradle.kts (project level)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android) apply false // this is what fixed it
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "2.0.0" apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.devtools.ksp) apply false
}

build.gradle.kts (:app)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlin.serialization)
    alias(libs.plugins.hilt)
    alias(libs.plugins.devtools.ksp)
}
...

dependencies {
    implementation(libs.hilt.android)
    ksp(libs.hilt.android.compiler)
    implementation(libs.hilt.navigation.compose)
}

